# North Korea's participation in Tokyo 2020 Summer olympics

Tags: japan, north-korea, olympics

Since Japan doesn't recognize North Korea as a country, nor they have embassy or formal diplomatic relations, how will North Korean Athletes participate in the next Summer Olympics if they can't receive travel visa to get into Japanese territory?

Comment: [Eight North Korean Athletes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea_at_the_1998_Winter_Olympics) participated in the 1998 Winter Games in Nagano;  so there's a precedent, at least.  Also, note that this will also be an issue (maybe a bigger one) for the 2018 Winter Olympics in Pyeongchang, South Korea.

Comment: Presumably this was addressed by the IOC when they awarded the games to Japan. Japan probably agreed to make an exception for participating athletes (and possibly visitors?).

Comment: Perhaps visas can be issued to _persons_.

Comment: I don't know enough about law to draft this as an answer, but North Korea is expected to compete in the (delayed) 2021 Summer Olympics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea_at_the_2020_Summer_Olympics

Answer (score 0):

### The Democratic People's Republic of Korea did not participate

[Citing Covid19, the DPRK did not send any athletes to the 2020 summer olympics held 2021 in Tokyo.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Summer_Olympics#Participating_National_Olympic_Committees) As such, the legal question became moot in April 2021 with the announcement of non-participation.

However, for [the 2022 Winter Games in Beijing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Winter_Olympics#Participating_National_Olympic_Committees), the IOC barred the Olympic Committee of the Democratic People's Republic of Korea from sending any participants due to their non-participation in the 2020 Summer Games. Participants from North Korea could appear under the non-national Olympic Flag, but none did attend.

[The ban was lifted for the 2024 Olympics in Paris.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea_at_the_2024_Summer_Olympics)